# How are the multiple number of records in a SELECT statement with multiple subqueries having LIMIT 1 in the subquery statements

Tags: sql, select, limit

```
SELECT
    (SELECT NAME FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION = 'Doctor'    ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT NAME FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION = 'Professor' ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT NAME FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION = 'Singer'    ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT NAME FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION = 'Actor'     ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 1)
FROM OCCUPATIONS
```

The output shows 10 records but I feel that it should return 1 single record as we already have a LIMIT 1 condition in the subquery.
Needed help with this!

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? What output do you want?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding what a `SELECT` query represents and how it's evaluated. `SELECT` queries are not evaluated in top-down order; logically they start with the `FROM` clause and the `SELECT` clause is evaluated **for every row** sourced from the `FROM` clause's expression. It's also generally a bad idea to nest an entire `SELECT` queries inside an outer query's `SELECT` clause _prior_ to the `FROM` (though putting additional `SELECT` queries inside the `FROM`, especially as `JOIN` expressions is actually quite correct).

Comment: Below is the OCCUPATIONS table description:

NAME (col1)         |     Occupation(col2)
----------------------------------------
Samantha    -     Doctor  |
Julia             -    Actor    |
Maria           -     Actor     |
Meera          -     Singer  |
Ashley         -     Professor    |
Ketty            -     Professor    |
Christeen     -     Professor   |
Jane            -      Actor          |
Jenny           -     Doctor        |

Comment: @Dai - I understand that evaluations starts from the FROM clause.
Since my subqueries returns only 1 record due to the LIMIT 1 condition, why am I getting 10 records for the outer SELECT query ?

Comment: @CleanBold I needed clarification for the above comment

Comment: @Pranshu93 Because of the **outer query** - which **also** has `FROM OCCUPATIONS` but nothing to limit _that_ query. I note that your outer-query isn't doing anything with the data in `OCCUPTATIONS` other than evaluating your subqueries **for each row**.

Comment: @Dai So why only 10 records ?
It could have shown more or less !

Comment: @Pranshu93 The evidence suggests it's because your `OCCUPATIONS` table contains 10 rows.

Comment: @Dai Got it !
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `FROM OCCUPATIONS` at the end of the query, it might give you what you want here:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT NAME FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION = 'Doctor'     ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 1), 
    (SELECT NAME FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION = 'Professor'  ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT NAME FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION = 'Singer'     ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT NAME FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION = 'Actor'      ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 1);
```

However, a more typical way to do this in MySQL would be via aggregation:

```sql
SELECT o1.NAME
FROM OCCUPATIONS o1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT OCCUPATION, MIN(NAME) AS NAME
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
    GROUP BY OCCUPATION
) o2
    ON o2.OCCUPATION = o1.OCCUPATION AND
       o2.NAME = o1.NAME;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` provides another approach:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY NAME) rn
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
)

SELECT NAME
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation!

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN OCCUPATION = 'Doctor' THEN NAME END),
       MIN(CASE WHEN OCCUPATION = 'Professor' THEN NAME END),
       MIN(CASE WHEN OCCUPATION = 'Singer' THEN NAME END),
       MIN(CASE WHEN OCCUPATION = 'Actor' THEN NAME END)
FROM OCCUPATIONS;
```

This seems like the simplest way to express your logic.

Your query is returning one row for every row in `OCCUPATIONS`, because the query has no filtering or aggregation.  Each row happens to have the same values, because the outer table isn't used anywhere in the query, other than in the `FROM` clause.

Conditional aggregation (as shown above) is a simpler way to express this logic.